# How to convert date dd/mm/YY to mm-dd-YY format in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a sample code:

```
<?php
$string = '07/01/2014'; // today format d/m/YY
echo date("m-d-Y", strtotime($string)); // result is 07-01-2014
?>
```

=> How t fix it to result is `01-07-2014` // today format `m-d-Y`

Comment: Compulsory reading about supported date formats if you're using strtotime - http://prototype.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use PHP's native `DateTime` object with its [`createFromFormat`](https://www.php.net/datetime.createfromformat) method:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y','07/01/2014')->format('m-d-Y');
echo $date; //01-07-2014
```